# iOS - RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have created in my application to the database using Realmsvift. Here is the output in the console. Please tell me, how do I read data from it in the application? For example, I want to display key-values: Oslo - 2.89. Thanks for the help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var city_list: [String] = ["Moscow", "London", "Oslo", "Paris"]
let realm = try! Realm()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let manager: ManagerData = ManagerData()
    for name in city_list {
        manager.loadJSON(city: name)
    }
    let localWeather = realm.objects(WeatherData.self)
    print(localWeather)
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

```
Results<WeatherData> (
[0] WeatherData {
    city_name = Moscow;
    tempList = RLMArray <0x6080002e2b00> (
        [0] Temp {
            temp = -4.25;
        }
    );
},
[1] WeatherData {
    city_name = London;
    tempList = RLMArray <0x6000002e4700> (
        [0] Temp {
            temp = 9.630000000000001;
        }
    );
},
[2] WeatherData {
    city_name = Paris;
    tempList = RLMArray <0x6000002e4800> (
        [0] Temp {
            temp = 6.59;
        }
    );
},
[3] WeatherData {
    city_name = Oslo;
    tempList = RLMArray <0x6000002e4900> (
        [0] Temp {
            temp = -2.89;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get properties from each model.

If that is the case, you're almost there. `localWeather` is like an array in the Realm's world (e.g., type of `Results<WeatherData>`).

You can just access it like normal swift's array/objects:

```
let firstWeather = localWeather[0]
let name = firstWeather.city_name
let temp = firstWeather.tempList[0].temp

// do what you want with 'name' and 'temp', e.g. key-value
print("\(name) - \(temp)")
```